# How do I rotate a background watermark image to landscape with iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm building a PDF class with iTextSharp to handle my company's digital records. We use expensive paper that has columns and has our company's logo at the top. I've scanned a copy as a PDF and another as a JPG. I've read elsewhere that the IMG.Rotate() command should rotate the image. I've also read that Image.SetRotationDegrees(90) is supposed to work, but that line of code doesn't work for me. SetRotationDegrees isn't a method of Image. Here's what I've got so far:

```
string imageFilePath = _watermark;
                iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);
                //Rotate it for landscape
                Image jpg.Rotate(); Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                //Scale image
                jpg.ScalePercent(35f);
                //Set position
                jpg.ScaleToFit(770, 3000);
                jpg.WidthPercentage = 100;
                jpg.Rotate();
                //Allignment
                jpg.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.UNDERLYING;
```

...

```
PDFReport.Add(jpg);
```

`

Anyone have any ideas? The image is being placed on the page but it places it portrait instead of landscape.

Comment: What version of iText(Sharp) are you using?

Comment: *"SetRotationDegrees isn't a method of Image"* - The Java method is `setRotationDegrees`. In C# it is a property `RotationDegrees`. Thus you need something like `jpg.RotationDegrees = 90`. That been said, the code you posted is so full of mistakes one hardly knows where to start correcting it.

Comment: Oh no! Yeah, sorry, new to programming. I'll give your recommendation a shot. Thanks!

Comment: It worked, I'm working on the position now. Thanks.